# Verificar com php e desativar option

Tags: php, foreach, for

Eu sei o que tem que fazer, mas não sei como fazer.

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
 $dados =  array
                       0 =>
                           array
                              'id' => 1
                              'posicao' => 1
                              'ativo' => 'sim'
                       1 =>
                           array
                              'id' => 2
                              'posicao' => 2
                              'ativo' => 'sim'
                       2 =>
                           array
                              'id' => 3
                              'posicao' => 3
                              'ativo' => 'sim'
                       3 =>
                           array
                              'id' => 4
                              'posicao' => 4
                              'ativo' => 'nao'
                       4 =>
                           array
                              'id' => 5
                              'posicao' => 5
                              'ativo' => 'nao'
```

Eu listo cada um destes itens com um loop `for` e em cada um tenho este `select`:

```
            <select>
                <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($dados); $i++) {  //para cada item do array eu faço um option ?>
                    <h3>Posição</h3>
                    <option value="<?php echo $dados[$i]['posicao'] ?>" <?php echo $selected = ($dados[$i]['posicao'] == $pos)? 'selected' : ' '; //verifico qual a posicao do item e seleciono?> ><?php echo $dados[$i]['posicao'] ?></option>
                <?php   } ?>
            </select>
```

Até aí está correto, agora eu preciso verificar em cada item do array se está ativo e caso estiver desative o `option`.

Segue imagem para questão didática:

[image: Itens]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer do seguinte formato

```
        <select name="posicao" id="posicao">
            <option  value="null" <?php echo $selected = ($dados[$i]['posicao'] == 'null')? 'selected' : ' '; ?>>Selecione</option>
            <?php 
            for ($i = 0; $pos < $i; $i++) { ?> 
                <option value="<?php echo $i ?>" <?php echo $selected = ($dados[$i]['posicao'] == $i)? 'selected' : ' '; ?>
                  <?php

                  //criei um loop com um if 

                    for ($ativo=0; $ativo < count($dados); $ativo++) { 
                        if ($i == $dados[$ativo]['posicao'] && $dados[$ativo]['ativo'] == 'sim') {
                            echo 'disabled';
                        }
                    }
                  ?>
                  ><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer parecido com oque foi feito para exibir o `selected`, segue o código abaixo:

```
<select>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < count($dados); $i++) {?>
     <h3>Posição</h3>
         <option value="<?php echo $dados[$i]['posicao'] ?>" <?php echo $selected = ($dados[$i]['posicao'] == $pos)? 'selected' : ' ';?> <?=($dados[$i]['ativo'] == 'nao' ? 'disabled' : '')?>><?php echo $dados[$i]['posicao'] ?></option>
     <?php   } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: eu até pensei em fazer deste formato, mas como comentei esse código vai estar dentro de outro loop também. Ou seja, caso a posição 1 esteja com um item `ativo` ele precisará aparecer para o outro item também e assim por diante.

Comment: acho que vai funcionar normal